# Putty SCP known_hosts file or StrictHostKeyChecking=no

Tags: windows, linux, scp

I need to be able to use a .known_hosts file or just disable checking, preferably the first option. I would be open to other ideas/software too, but hopefully someone can tell me how to do this with PSCP.EXE

I'm using windows to SCP to and from a linux box.

Comment: See [StrictHostKeyChecking config on PSFTP.EXE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25978461/850848)

Answer (score 1):

Can you accept simply [importing](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/misc/CD/known_hosts.d/kh2reg.py) a known hosts file into the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys`?  The linked script does appear to permit this.